# What is the interpretation of the real part of $s$ in the Lapace transform?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

In the Laplace Transform, we perform:

$$F(s) = \int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt$$

With some interpretations of $s$ being that $s = \sigma + i \omega$.  It is natural to consider $\omega$ as the frequency of a sine wave, but what about $\sigma$?  Is it phase?  If so, with respect to what?

I know that in engineering, a second order system is represented in the $s$ domain and the location of the poles of that system relate to the damping coefficient of the system.  In that case, the $s$ coordinates of the poles make sense as a damping term.  However, the Laplace Transform is not defined only at the poles of rational functions.  So here are two questions, one of which is a special case:

In terms of the engineering case I mentioned above, what does $\sigma$ represent in terms of the "frequency domain" representation of a physical system's mathematical model?

More generally, what is the interpretation of that real part?

Comment: In the Laplace transform, the lower bound of the integration interval is usually zero. Are you using a different variant?

Comment: @Dr.LutzLehmann edited, thanks